# Is there a way to render my Termbox game and handle keyboard events in the same loop?

Tags: c, render

I'm having issues with my termbox program rendering the screen and handling keyboard events. Recently, I've finished a C and C++ class at my university. I wanted to demonstrate my knowledge by creating a basic Snake game. The first steps, I wanted to get a simple render loop going and have a block of text simply move leftward and exit the game upon reaching the 0th x-coordinate. The issue arises when continuing to the next render frame, because the game is running single-threaded the next frame won't be rendered until a new keyboard event is accepted. Ordinarily, I would expect the game to continue rendering regardless of events, new events affecting the new frame.

As for potential solutions, I thought about using multiple threads to run the game loop and handle keyboard events. But, I think this would be overkill for such a small problem, there are likely easier alternatives than having to manage multiple threads for a simple snake game.

As for the code, it's as simple as:

```cpp
while (1)
{
    tb_clear();
    draw(gameState);
    tb_present();

    struct tb_event event;
    tb_poll_event(&event);

    if (event.ch == 'q')
        break;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". Which language are you using? C? Or C++? Then tag that _one_.

Comment: I'm not familiar with termbox, but most keyboard libraries allow you to read the state of the keyboard without blocking (i.e. without waiting for input). Then you can compare the state of the keyboard with last frame's state and determine whether a key was pressed.

Comment: _"there are likely easier alternatives than having to manage multiple threads for a simple snake game."_ Dunno, sounds like a decent solution to me. And threads are pretty trivial to manage in C++ nowadays.

Comment: The termbox library exists on both C and C++, the functionality is pretty similar which is why I tagged both, I'll keep a mental note for next time.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with tembox. But most event loop frameworks have a timeout. If that is the case you can set the timeout based on your desired rendering refresh rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through the header file a bit more I found a method which doesn't wait forever.

```cpp
/* Wait for an event up to 'timeout' milliseconds and fill the 'event'
 * structure with it, when the event is available. Returns the type of the
 * event (one of TB_EVENT_* constants) or -1 if there was an error or 0 in case
 * there were no event during 'timeout' period.
 */
SO_IMPORT int tb_peek_event(struct tb_event *event, int timeout);
```